# Is it possible to build an opengl game with haxe nme in ios and android?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, haxe, nme

i understand haxe nme can use opengl in the backend to display the 2D sprites of the games, but is it possible to manipulate opengl directly from nme to build a cross platform ios and android pure 3D opengl game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question came up on the haxelang Google Group just a few days ago.

From Discussion [Are there any 3d engines working on NME?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/haxelang/BMKaQhUyZoo/8cHtOyQb2tEJ):

> NME frontend renderer on desktop and mobile uses OpenGL(ES) 1.x at the moment (I think Hugh is doing work on an upcoming OpenGL(ES) 2.x renderer as well). Which means that as far as NME is concerned, the whole display list is nothing more than a 3D scene.
>
> Extrapolating from that, and assuming that you'd be targetting only mobile and desktop platforms, it pretty much means that you could use any OpenGL function quite easily on NME.
>
> Now, here's the issue: there's no opengl binding for Haxe that you could use on NME as of now. It shouldn't be hard to implement (maybe as an NME extension), because you could basically write a one-to-one mapping, but it hasn't been done AFAIK

Short answer - it is possible, but it hasn't been implemented yet.  If you want to pursue getting this working, the best place to ask would be the [Haxe mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/haxelang?hl=en) or [NME forums](http://www.haxenme.org/community/forums/).

Comment: I found a haxe opengl library: http://lib.haxe.org/p/opengl